# sql procedure copy file to local computer error

Tags: sql, synchronization

My purpose is:

When the sql procedure backup database completed,copy the bak file to local computer.When copying file,my computer and the server in loacl Network.

This is my procedure(bak DB have complete):

```
create procedure CopyFile
as
begin
    declare @DynamicSQL varchar(1000)
    set @DynamicSQL='net use \\Dolphin-PC\ipc$ 123 /user:Administrator&&xcopy E:\"Database backup"\%Date:~0,4%%Date:~5,2%%Date:~8,2%\*.bak  \\Dolphin-PC\D$\邮电\LocalDB\%Date:~0,4%%Date:~5,2%%Date:~8,2%\ /E /Y /H /K&&net use \\Dolphin-PC\ipc$ /delete'   
    --Configure extension procedure the cmd_shell enable
    exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
    reconfigure;
    exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1;
    reconfigure;    
    exec xp_cmdshell @DynamicSQL
    --Configure extended procedure cmd_shell disable
    exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
    reconfigure;
    exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',0;
    reconfigure;
end
```

When i run the proc,it tips that:

```
occour system error 1312。
NULL
the session have not been complete.Maybe have been finished.
NULL
NULL
```

I run in the `DOS` have no problem.The `DOS` command is:

```
net use \\Dolphin-PC\ipc$ 123 /user:Administrator
xcopy E:\"Database backup"\%Date:~0,4%%Date:~5,2%%Date:~8,2%\*.bak  \\Dolphin-PC\D$\邮电\LocalDB\%Date:~0,4%%Date:~5,2%%Date:~8,2%\ /E /Y /H /K
net use \\Dolphin-PC\ipc$ /delete
```

Execute the batch with sql the another way:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
    reconfigure;
    exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1;
    reconfigure;    
    exec xp_cmdshell 'E:\"Database backup"\bakcpy.bat'
    --Configure extended procedure cmd_shell disable
    exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
    reconfigure;
    exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',0;
    reconfigure;
```

The error is:

```
NULL
C:\Windows\system32>net use \\Dolphin-PC\ipc$ 123 /user:Administrator 
occur system error 1312.
NULL
The login session does not exits.Maybe finished.
NULL
NULL
C:\Windows\system32>xcopy E:\"Database backup"\20131115\*.bak  \\Dolphin-PC\D$\js\LocalDB\20131115\ /E /Y /H /K 
invalid disk format
 0 file have been copied
NULL
C:\Windows\system32>net use \\Dolphin-PC\ipc$ /delete 
Can't find network connection.
NULL
input NET HELPMSG 2250 to get more help
NULL
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your DOS command into a batch file. Run the batch file from your stored procedure instead. This will remove any issues around single quotes and spaces.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? If so can you update the question with the batch file? Can you post the exact error that you see? The error that you have posted doesn't sound like a normal error message.